# add strip plot to bottom of geom_density

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add a strip plot to the bottom of a `geom_density` plot... I could do something like :

```
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_density(fill = "#2D708EFF", alpha = .2) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = 0), alpha = .4, shape = 73, size = 6)
```

[image: code output]

But is there a more elegant way of doing this with `ggplot2`? My keywords might be off, but so far I haven't been able to find another `ggplot2` solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be looking for `geom_rug()`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_density(fill = "#2D708EFF", alpha = .2) + 
  # geom_point(aes(y = 0), alpha = .4, shape = 73, size = 6) +
  geom_rug()
```

> A rug plot is a compact visualisation designed to supplement a 2d display with the two 1d marginal distributions. Rug plots display individual cases so are best used with smaller datasets.

[image]